# Hide or show different DIV based on numerical value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hide, show

I have a form where depending on the value of the #balance field i want a certain div to show. If the #balance field is a number greater than one i want to show the div #moreassets but if the #balance field is a negative number i want it to show the div #moreliabilities.

This script below works calculating the value of two previous fields in the same form but when i try and add further or a separate or second peice of js code for the show hide function i get stuck.

I have tried numerous methods but can’t seem to get it to work. Im not great at this kind of stuff, but im assuming that perhaps my issue is that i am already using #balance in the DOM or whatever so cant use the same thing twice?

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction or what i would need to add to the below script / code to make this happen?

```
<label style="margin-top: 20px;">Your Balance: </label>

<input class="form-control text-center balance" id="balance" type="type" name="balance">

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#assets2, #liabilities').change(function() {
      var yourassets = parseFloat($('#assets2').val()) || 0;
      var yourliabilities = parseFloat($('#liabilities').val()) || 0;
      $('#balance').val(yourassets - yourliabilities);
    });
  });

</script>

<div id="moreliabilities" class="callout">
  <p>Personal liabilities, such as credit cards and loans, can be expensive and you should consider making overpayments before investing.</p>
</div>

<div id="moreassets" class="callout">
  <p>You have more assets than liabilities.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toggle` and pass boolean expression as per difference value.
see below code

```js
$(function() {
  $('#assets2, #liabilities').change(function() {
    var yourassets = parseFloat($('#assets2').val()) || 0;
    var yourliabilities = parseFloat($('#liabilities').val()) || 0;
    var diff = yourassets - yourliabilities;
    $('#balance').val(diff);
    $('#moreassets').toggle(diff>0);
    $('#moreliabilities').toggle(diff<0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control text-center" id="assets2" type="type" name="assets2"><br>
<input class="form-control text-center" id="liabilities" type="type" name="liabilities"><br>
<label style="margin-top: 20px;">Your Balance: </label>
<input class="form-control text-center balance" id="balance" type="type" name="balance">
<div id="moreliabilities" class="callout">
  <p>Personal liabilities, such as credit cards and loans, can be expensive and you should consider making overpayments before investing.</p>
</div>

<div id="moreassets" class="callout">
  <p>You have more assets than liabilities.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute Legend